# In bash, is there a way to suspend a script, let a user enter some commands, and then resume the script once they are done?

Tags: bash

I might be approaching this the wrong way, but I am currently writing a script that will deploy some files between environments. The script will be pulling these files from a dev server, and manual edits will need to be made so they work properly once deployed on a test cluster.

I want the user to be able to use vim in the middle of this deploy script to make these edits before the file is then copied to other servers in the test cluster. Then, they could signify they've finished and the script will pick up where it left off. Is this possible?

Comment: `read` can take in input. `eval` can run that input as a command. you can put those in a `while` loop and have some keyword be the trigger to stop.

Comment: that being said, you likely are approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I would like these things that need to be changed variablized, but I am not developing the application that uses these properties files unfortunately. This is the solution I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is running interactively, simply invoke an editor on the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world" > myfile.txt
${EDITOR:-nano} myfile.txt

echo "Here's what you ended up saving:"
cat myfile.txt
```

This opens the user's preferred editor (with fallback on nano), and will not continue until the user quits the editor. This is similar to how an editor opens when you use `git commit`.

You can similarly give the user an interactive shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please run any commands you want, and 'exit' when done"
bash
echo "Ok, continuing"
```

In this case, a shell starts, the user can run whichever commands they want, and when they exit the shell using `exit` or Ctrl+D, the script continues.

Comment: @chepner Quoting `$EDITOR` will break flags though

Comment: I can't find any defined semantics for `EDITOR`, but I don't think it's safe to assume that its value will undergo word-splitting by a program using it. Specifically, you can't assume a program using it will subject it to shell-style word-splitting; `EDITOR="vi -R"` should attempt to run a program named `vi -R`, not `vi` with a `-R` option.

Comment: @chepner I wasn't able to find any programs that behave that way. `man`, `crontab`, `git`, `visudo`, `zmore` and `bash` itself all do word splitting on PAGER and EDITOR.